# Getting error while uploading dataframe into pgadmin using to_postgis

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I have a dataframe *stations_gdf*, and I want to upload this dataframe in pgAdmin, using the following code, but I am getting error, and I dont have anz idea how could I solve that :(
Can anybody help me please?

The error is ***DuplicateTable: relation "idx_stations_geometry" already exists***

[image]

After running the following code, I am getting error:

```
# Set data types in PG explicitly.
dtypes = {"station_id": Numeric(6,0), "altitude" : REAL, "date_from" : Date, "date_to" : Date, "longitude" : REAL, "latitude" : REAL}
engine.execute("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dwd.v_stations_prec")
stations_gdf.to_postgis(name="stations", schema="dwd", if_exists = "replace", index = "station_id", index_label=True, con=engine, dtype=dtypes)
engine.execute('alter table dwd.stations add primary key (station_id)')
```

Error:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DuplicateTable                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1801                 if not evt_handled:
-> 1802                     self.dialect.do_execute(
   1803                         cursor, statement, parameters, context

~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    731     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 732         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    733 

DuplicateTable: relation "idx_stations_geometry" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2184/2370298131.py in <module>
     10 engine.execute("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dwd.v_stations_prec")
     11 
---> 12 stations_gdf.to_postgis(name="stations", schema="dwd", if_exists = "replace", index = "station_id", index_label=True, con=engine, dtype=dtypes)
     13 
     14 #engine.execute('alter table dwd.stations add constraint my_awesome_pkey primary key (station_id)')

~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_postgis(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
   1806 
   1807         """
-> 1808         geopandas.io.sql._write_postgis(
   1809             self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype
   1810         )

~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\sql.py in _write_postgis(gdf, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    429     with _get_conn(con) as connection:
    430 
--> 431         gdf.to_sql(
    432             name,
    433             connection,

~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2870         from pandas.io import sql
   2871 
-> 2872         sql.to_sql(
   2873             self,
   2874             name,

~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
    715         )
    716 
--> 717     pandas_sql.to_sql(
    718         frame,
    719         name,

~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
   1749         sql_engine = get_engine(engine)
   1750 
-> 1751         table = self.prep_table(
   1752             frame=frame,
   1753             name=name,
-------------------------------------

~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _run_ddl_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
   2111 
   2112         """
-> 2113         visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
   2114 
   2115     @util.deprecated(

   
~\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    730 
    731     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 732         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    733 
    734     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable) relation "idx_stations_geometry" already exists

[SQL: CREATE INDEX idx_stations_geometry ON dwd.stations USING gist (geometry)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

How can I solve this issue? I tried using different database and different schema, still, I am getting this error. What is the problem here?